# Installing Android in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

Yesterday Android stopped working in my Eclipse. It gives the following error code:

[image]

I read in this forum that I should do it from Help -> install new software.

I did it, but the Eclipse is blocked installing:

[image]

I have waited for one day and this message is still blinking. How should it be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
please go to help tab in eclipse and click on check for updates and please update the ADT plugin
```

Answer (score 1):

visit and download new SDK from android website

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html